# Git; Pull from one IP range, Push from another

Tags: git

I need to configure git so that I can push to a git server from one ip range, but can only pull from that server to another range? Is there any way to do this without running two servers, where one pushes to another server (which can be pulled from) as a post-commit?

The reason for doing this is that we're trying to create a network clean-room, where data cannot be extracted, but users can still upload code, and we can see those changes.

EDIT: Current I'm using git through Apache and the smart HTTP git CGI script.
Thanks,

Comment: How are you interacting with the git server? Using ssh, http(s) and/or the bare git protocol? Open for a solution where push is restricted to ssh, but where you can also pull using https? Running any special software as your Git server?

Comment: Edited the original question to provide more information.